# Google Analytics: _linkbypost() on non-form cross domain links?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm just curious is it possible (or advisable) to use _linkbypost() instead of just _link() on cross domain links with Google Analytics to avoid the problems I'm having with the long query strings that _link() produces.

_link() uses _GET to pass data by attaching a huge gibberish query string to the destination url which causes me a few headaches: It prevents my caching scheme (which keys off exact matching urls), drives many of my social media widgets crazy (which have proven super important to my business), and just looks scary and ugly which I've found really does affect how much many users trust your site.

So I'm hoping I can get the same ability to track without losing my clean orderly cacheable urls by passing that data via post instead of get. But since I don't really understand how post works I don't know if this if feasible, or if it is just a really bad idea for some other reason.

I know _linkbypost() needs a form object to function, so my plan was to add an onSubmit function to each cross-domain link like so:

```
var crossLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
var formHTML = '<form id="crossForm" action="'+crossLink+'" method="post"></form>';
$('body').append(formHTML);
var crossForm = $('#crossForm');
_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', crossForm]);
return false;
```

Assuming it's not a bad idea to begin with, does that implementation seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure _linkByPost will still sen the data through your url. So I don't think that's a solution to your problem.

You can use _link to pass the query parameters at the anchor (instead as query parameters) part of the url using it's second argument as true.

```
_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.myothersite.com', true]);
```

This will generate a url like

```
http://www.myothersite.com#__utma=1.2.123123...
```

You will also need `_gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);` to tell GA to read the data from the Anchor.

It should be enough to not break your cache anymore and reduce the issue with your social plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Ok, that gets rid of the biggest problems, and will be a good enough solution for now. But pushing forward if I wanted to pursue my goal of 100% clean urls do you know if there is any way to take the data from the linker, pass it as post data myself and then manually add the cookies myself before loading the analytics tracker and have it work correctly? I altered my above scheme to pass all the __ut* variables as hidden form data via post. How does analytics read the query data normally, and any tips on mimicking the effect on my side? Thanks!